# Como hacer una pagina tipo slider a pantalla completa pero solo con una imagen?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

debo hacer una pagina tipo slider a pantalla completa pero solo con esta  imagen, con botones al costado para que se vaya moviendo al siguiente cuadro. Necesito ideas por favor. Solo puedo usar js y css ***nada de jquery/bootstrap***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La opción mas simple sería cortar la imagen y añadir un efecto de transición entre todas las partes de la imagen, aunque en las respuestas a tu pregunta hay otro método.

Comment: Recuerda que todo lo que subas a [es.so] está bajo la licencia [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), ten cuidado con subir algo que pueda estar afectado por derechos de autor

Answer (score 1):

Algo como esto te debería funcionar

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
  <title>slider</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
   }

   #wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRUVn.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-size:auto 100%;
   }
   a{
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background:#0000ff;
    opacity:0.5;
   }
   a:hover{
    background:#ff0000;
   }
  </style>
  <script>
   var position = 0;
  function move(direction) {
   position = position + direction * 500; //ancho del desplazamiento deseado
   document.getElementById('wrapper').style.backgroundPosition = position + 'px 0px';
  }
   
  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  
  <a href="#" id="link1" onclick="move(1)" class="link" style="top:50%;left:10px;"></a>
  <a href="#" id="link2" onclick="move(-1)" class="link" style="top:50%;right:10px;"></a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Donde `01.jpg` es tu imagen de fondo y `position = position + direction * 500;` es el desplazamiento segun tu imagen

Saludos!